# AWS command line tools broken : (

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terminal, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I tried to install awscli after ebcli, and they both broke. Currently, if I type aws s3 ls, it just hangs with no response, and if I try to use eb, I get this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/eb", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('awsebcli==3.8.4', 'console_scripts', 'eb')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2291, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ebcli/core/ebcore.py", line 43, in <module>
    from . import ebglobals, base, io, hooks
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ebcli/core/base.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ebcli import __version__
ImportError: cannot import name __version__`

I basically need to have command line tools for s3 and elastic beanstalk, but I apparently have no luck, and will be spending my entire day googling the universe, and combing through error codes to try and fix this : (

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 on a Thinkpad.

Comment: Doesn't `AWS CLI` include `ebs` too? How did you (command) install the CLIs? Not a big deal. Can be fixed.

Comment: It does, but it's a different command line tool, with a different list of commands that I'm not used to. It's also aws elasticbeanstalk and all the commands are super wordy.

Comment: I installed awsebcli using pip, and then months later, just now, I installed awscli using pip, and it broke eb. And the aws tools don't really work well. aws s3 ls just hangs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite common for different Python libraries to install over each other, causing problems like this.

A popular fix is to use a the [**virtualenv**](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) tool to create **isolated Python environments**.

The AWS documentation for `awsebcli` has a page showing how: [Install the EB CLI in a Virtual Environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-virtualenv.html)

Alternatively, keep using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) since it works across all AWS services, rather than using service-specific command sets like `awsebcli` (which pre-date the CLI).

Comment: Thanks so much John! My AWS commands hang with no error codes, I'm having trouble debugging those.

Comment: A hanging CLI command is often indicative of failure to connect with the AWS endpoint. Check your network connectivity (eg firewalls) to ensure communication. Also, make sure that your `region` setting is correct, eg `us-west-2` rather than `us-west-2a`.

Comment: Ahhhh, you rock!!!! It was the region configuration. The default is `us-east` which at one point was correct. What was `us-east` is now called `us-east-1`. Thanks, John!!!

Comment: Any idea where I can report this bug? That default is misleading.

Comment: If you can find documentation with incorrect information, just hit the Feedback button. It's probably because a new `us-east-2` region was introduced.